# Camera won’t focus / stay focused in Appcelerator app

Tags: ios, appcelerator

After using the app for a while and taking dozens and dozens of photos successfully, users report the Camera will not autofocus and the photos are blurry using our Appcelerator app.

**What is causing the camera app not to auto-focus?**

This has been reported by a number of users on different model (iPad) devices.

We are taking a lot of photo's and it is difficult to determine why/what makes the camera auto-focus stop working. The code to capture the photo/image is very basic and shown below:

```
            Ti.Media.showCamera(
                {   showControls:true,
                      mediaTypes:[Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO],
                         success:function(e){
                                     try{
                                            imgPhoto.image = e.media;                                              
                                     }
                                     catch(e){                                                          
                                        require('lib/Error').Capture(e);                                        
                                     }      
                                },
                       error:function(e){
                                require('lib/Error').Capture(e);
                             }
             });
```

Obviously we tried resetting the device, killing the app, etc. and these solutions fix the problem temporarily. Any solid advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the below in `tiapp.xml`

```
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>

<array>
  <string>auto-focus-camera</string>
```

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: What is the SDK that you are using.

Comment: all current 5.x,6.x